# How can i start start the main activity(foregorundservice) at boot time?

Tags: android, boot, foreground-service

I want the service to start automatically when the phone boots up. But it doesn't run. I also created a foreground service so that the main activity can run in the background.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())){
        Intent tempService = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            context.startForegroundService(tempService);
        }else{
            context.startService(tempService);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to execute the method in the main activity after executing the class called myService, but I can't do that. You need another way.I tried to execute public void onreceive in the code below, but I couldn't find a way in the end.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive() {
        //my code
    }
};
```

Comment: Please refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions